# Typescript 4.4.3 : How to pass string as key and extract its value(list)

Tags: javascript, angular13, typeguards, typescript4.0

I have a list of array something like this:

```
//model.ts
export class Item{
    name: string;
    age: string;
    Id: number;
}

export class TempArray{ 
  [key : string] : PubMedDetails[];
}

//component.ts

listOfItems: Item[] = []
listOfTempArray: TempArray[] = [];

listOfTempArray ={
'class2':{'name': 'abc', 'age': 'ten', 'Id': 3398},
'class3':{'name': 'Radha','age': 'two', 'Id': 9876},
'class4':{'name': 'hjgf', 'age': 'five', 'Id': 8766}
}

 FetchData() {
    let che: keyof TempArray = 'Radha' //I will be receiving this value from UI as ngModel
    //trying to assign Radha's details to listOfItems
    this.listOfItems = this.listOfTempArray[che] //line 4

    this.listOfItems.forEach(x => {
      if (this.listOfDiseaseNames.indexOf(x.names.toLowerCase()) == -1) { //line 7
        this.listOfDiseaseNames.push(x.names.toLowerCase())   //line 8
      }
    })
  }
```

```
tempArray = {
'class2':{'name': 'abc', 'age': 'ten', 'Id': 3398},
'class3':{'name': 'gg', 'age': 'two', 'Id': 9876},
'class4':{'name': 'hjgf', 'age': 'five', 'Id': 8766}
}
```

in Typescript v4.4 (angular 13) how do I get the values of class4 by passing 'class4'(string) as key

Errors I am getting:
in line 4 :Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.
in line 7 and 8 : Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you initialize `listOfTempArray` as array of `TempArray`:

```
listOfTempArray: TempArray[] = [];
```

But later you refer to it as it was of type `TempArray`, not `TempArray[]`

```
FetchData() {
    let che: keyof TempArray = 'Radha' //I will be receiving this value from UI as ngModel
    //trying to assign Radha's details to listOfItems
    this.listOfItems = this.listOfTempArray[che] // here should be either this.listOfTempArray[index][che] for TempArray[] type OR this.listOfTempArray[che], but with TempArray type

    this.listOfItems.forEach(x => {
      if (this.listOfDiseaseNames.indexOf(x.names.toLowerCase()) == -1) { //line 7
        this.listOfDiseaseNames.push(x.names.toLowerCase())   //line 8
      }
    })
  }
```

Line 7 and 8 errors should disappear when you resolve line 4 error.

Comment: I have added the code from component and error message. Could you please help me @deaponn

Comment: I have edited my answer. For future, adding your code right away will make answering faster

Comment: Done already... Any clue on where I can read about typescript 4.4

Comment: Upvoting is not marking as correct, you need to click the tick mark below downvoting arrow. Here is Typescript 4.4 official documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html